# Redirect Block Controller view()

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-8.x

From `view()` of a single page controller I can redirect like following:

```php
use \Concrete\Core\Http\ResponseFactory;
return ResponseFactory::redirect($this->getRequest()->getPathInfo());
```

From the `view()` method of a block controller the redirection with the above snippet does not work.
I also tried to return the value of the `AbstractController::buildRedirect()` with no success.

Therefor my question is: What kind of support from c5 does exist to redierct from `view()` of a block controller?

Comment: The way the redirection works on `view()` of a block controller is: `ResponseFactory::redirect($this->getRequest()->getPathInfo())->send();`. But then a new question arises: why do page and block controllers handle it different? Shouldn't it be handled the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility is, as I mentioned in the comment, to send the response. But then the script has to be exited to avoid rendering the view.
The related snippet would be as following:

```php
$this->app->make(ResponseFactoryInterface::class)
        ->redirect($this->getRequest()->getPathInfo())
        ->send();
exit;
```

Comment: Open questions: Best practice? Is the different handling (page-/block controller) a bug or as intended?